# How do i not include latest record but all record from an object in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

For example if i want to pull all @posts using @posts.all but i dont want to include the very last or latest record from that?

here is what i am trying to do,

@posts = Post.all(Without the very very latest record that was created.)

Basically all record but not the very last record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is not worth it to try to generate a SQL query that excludes the very last element. Especially a subquery might be slower than just loading all records into an `Array` and than excluding the last:

```
@posts = Post.all[0..-2]
```

Your other example from the comments would look like this:

```
@contact_prices = @contact.retail_prices.all.order("created_at DESC").load[0..-2]
```

Another option (depending on the order of your relation) might be to use [`offset`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/offset):

```
@contact_prices = @contact.retail_prices.order("created_at DESC").offset(1)
```

Comment: so i have this object, @contact_prices = @contact.retail_prices.all.order("created_at DESC") and that didnt work

Comment: This will return an array not an AR object

Comment: I would argue that the OP didn't define that he need a `Relation` and not an `Array`.

Comment: He asks for the same type of result than Post.all, doesn't he?

Comment: so if i were to do @posts.all.load[0..Post.count] , the "0" will be the latest record?

Comment: @CV-Gate : Perhaps it is just me, but I don't understand the OP asking for a specific type.

Comment: this worked for me @contact_prices = @contact.retail_prices.all.order("created_at DESC").load[1..@contact.retail_prices.count] , I was trying to pull all record BUT the very newest one.

Comment: @suyesh : No in `[0..Post.count]` `0` is the first record `Post.count` will be one record after the last (because Arrays start to count from `0`). `-1` is always the last, `-2` is always up to the second last.

Comment: I am surprised, because `[1..@contact.retail_prices.count]` would skip the first. Than it might be better to just use `offset(1)`

Comment: Offset(1) is what I was looking for. Thank you.  Post it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is the most direct way I think of doing what you're trying to do:

```
Post.limit(Post.count - 1)
```

If you want your query to allow pagination or other LIMIT queries, you could try something like

```
Post.where("id < ?", Post.last.id)
```

Comment: Not really race conditions, just getting a count that's out of sync. Doesn't seem too important in this case, but +1 for thoroughness for sure. I think the details of how to implement the transaction depends on how locked down you want it to be (e.g. you could lock it to make sure no Posts get created or deleted in the middle, but I'm thinking that's too heavy handed). The worst case without ensuring data synchrony is that you get a post you shouldn't have, or you don't get one you should have, but that's the same as if you'd executed the line a moment prior.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of answers that will do the trick, but throwing out an additional option:

```
@posts = Post.where("id != ?", Post.last.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

One line AR:

```
Post.where.not(id: Post.last&.id)
```